# Reg login to open cart admin panel and 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

i cant login to admin panel of open cart(ie. example.com/admin) when I has put redirect from www to non www in .htaccess file

But when the redirect(from non-www to www) was removed, I can login to the open cart admin panel

**Problem is** : When i login to opencart admin panel successfully,here 2 same name domains are displaying, any one can help what can i do in .htaccess file or in opencart  admin panel

Comment: Put the bad code from .htaccess to your question

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change your `HTTPS_SERVER` in `/admin/config.php` to reflect your domain name correctly. So change

```
http://yoursite.com/admin/
```

to

```
http://www.yoursite.com/admin/
```

You should also change your `HTTP_SERVER` in there too though it's not really a necessity